# Is there a way to read notification color from phone style and set it in remoteViews?

Tags: android, notifications

I decided to make a specific notification layout for my application and used remoreViews. But when I started testing, I realized that the background color is wrong. The default background color in default notifications depends on the theme of the phone, but remoteViews does not use it. How to set it?

[image]
[image]

I have searched for a solution and have not been successful.

There are only text styles that I have found.

```
@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification
```